# Filling a MultipleWidget from database

Tags: django, django-models, jquery-select2

I'm trying to get a list of weekday options into a `PositiveSmallIntegerField` in Django and back to the form.

I found a very similar question from the year 2011 which covers the process of having a MultiSelect widget with weekday options, [Representing a multi-select field for weekdays in a Django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663898/representing-a-multi-select-field-for-weekdays-in-a-django-model). Also, there has been an additional question regarding the reverse process, [Custo widget based on CheckBoxMultipleSelect for weekdays in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25575951/custom-widget-based-on-checkboxmultipleselect-for-weekdays-in-django) by user gabn88, which sadly has been deleted since.

I tried the approach with the BitChoices class in the first post, and the class itself seems to work. However, I fail to put the selection back to something I can fill the form with. At least that's what I think judging from the error message on my view:

```
Select a valid choice. ['2', '16', '128'] is not one of the available choices.
```

Can anybody help me out, please?